# Certain lines are not triggering

Tags: c#

I am making a 3D text based game. When I start the program, it executes the line "hit x to exit" but it doesn't execute any other lines of code in method Game. This is the entire program. If you can figure out what's wrong, it would be helpful.

```
using System;
namespace ThreeDGame {
    class Player {
        private int px=1;
        public int Px {
            get {return px;}
            set {px = value;}
        }
        private int py=1;
        public int Py {
            get {return py;}
            set {py = value;}
        }
        private int pz=1;
        public int Pz {
            get {return pz;}
            set {pz = value;}
        }
        public Player(int x, int y, int z) {
            px=x;
            py=y;
            pz=z;
        }
        public void xp() {
            px++;
            if (px==10) {
                px=1;
            }
        }
        public void xn() {
            px--;
            if (px==0) {
                px=9;
            }
        }
        public void yp() {
            py++;
            if (py==10) {
                py=1;
            }
        }
        public void yn() {
            py--;
            if (py==0) {
                py=9;
            }
        }
        public void zp() {
            pz++;
            if (pz==10) {
                pz=1;
            }
        }
        public void zn() {
            pz--;
            if (pz==0) {
                pz=9;
            }
        }
    }
    class Board {
        public char[,,] board = new char[9,9,9];
        Player o = new Player(1,1,1);
        public Board() {
            for (int x=0;x<board.GetLength(0);++x) {
                for (int y=0;y<board.GetLength(1);++y) {
                    for (int z=0;z<board.GetLength(2);++z) {
                        board[x,y,z] = '~';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public void DispBoard(int z) {
            for (int a=0;a<board.GetLength(0);a++) {
                Console.WriteLine();
                for (int b=0;b<board.GetLength(1);b++) {
                    Console.Write(board[a,b,z]);
                }
            }
        }
        public void Move(char dir) {
            switch (dir) {
                case 'w':{
                    o.yn();
                    break;
                }
                case 's':{
                    o.yp();
                    break;
                }
                case 'a':{
                    o.xn();
                    break;
                }
                case 'd':{
                    o.xp();
                    break;
                }
                case 'q':{
                    o.zn();
                    break;
                }
                case 'e':{
                    o.zp();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        public void PlayerPosOnBoard() {
            board[o.Px,o.Py,o.Pz] = '@';
        }
        public void Game() {
            Console.Write("Hit x to exit");
            for (int x=0;x==1;x=x)  {
                char c = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
                switch (c) {
                    case 'x':{
                        x=1;
                        break;
                    }
                    default:{
                        Move(c);
                        DispBoard(o.Pz);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    class Game {
                static void Main() {
                Board b = new Board();
                b.Game();
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect this loop to do and why? `for (int x=0;x==1;x=x)` Seems like a while loop would be much better suited here.

Comment: I think you meant `x!=1`.

Comment: Time to learn to use a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```
for (int x=0;x==1;x=x)
```

will cause the loop to never run. The second element `x==1` is the condition that is being checked, and it is false since the initializer sets x to zero.

Look at some documentation of for loops to understand better.